# compiler cannot infer generic types by where clause

Tags: generics, rust

```rust
use futures::{Future, Stream};
use async_trait::async_trait;
use bytes::Bytes;
use std::error::Error as StdError;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use hyper::{Request, Response, Body};
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::convert::Infallible;


#[async_trait]
pub trait Storer<'a, S, E>
where
    S: Stream<Item = Result<Bytes, E>> + Sized + Send + Unpin + 'a,
    E: StdError + Send + Sync + 'a,
{
    async fn put(&'a self, ext: &str, content: S) -> Result<String, Box<E>>;
}


async fn put<'a, S, E, F>(store: Arc<Mutex<dyn Storer<'a, S, E>>>) -> impl Fn(Request<Body>) -> Pin<Box<Future<Output = Result<Response<hyper::Body>, Infallible>>>>
where
    S: Stream<Item = Result<Bytes, E>>,
    E: StdError + Send + Sync,
{
    |req| async move { Ok::<_, Infallible>(Response::new(Body::default())) }.boxed()
}
```

this can be compiled successfully, but when i modify the signature of `put` function like below:

```rust
async fn put<'a, S, E, F>(store: Arc<Mutex<dyn Storer<'a, S, E>>>) -> impl Fn(Request<Body>) -> Pin<Box<F>>
where
    S: Stream<Item = Result<Bytes, E>>,
    E: StdError + Send + Sync,
    F: Future<Output = Result<Response<hyper::Body>, Infallible>>,
{
    |req| async move { Ok::<_, Infallible>(Response::new(Body::default())) }.boxed()
}
```

compiler reported a weird error:

```
mismatched types
expected struct `Pin<Box<F>>`
   found struct `Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = Result<hyper::Response<hyper::Body>, Infallible>> + std::marker::Send>>`
type parameters must be constrained to match other types
```

I just moved the `Future<Output = Result<Response<hyper::Body>, Infallible>>` out of `Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Response<hyper::Body>, Infallible>>>>` and put it into the where clause. Compiler cannot recognize them as same.Why `Pin<Box<F>>` is not equal to `Pin<Box<Future<Output = Result<Response<hyper::Body>, Infallible>>>>`?

Comment: Concrete values for the generic parameter `F` are chosen by callers of the `put` function, but the function's return value is not guaranteed to match the type that the caller chose.  Returning `dyn ...` allows any concrete type that implements the trait.

Comment: @eggyal you mean `F: ...` is a generic type and `dyn ...` is a specific type, right?

Comment: Apologies, perhaps I wasn’t specific enough.  Yes, `F` is generic but when the function is invoked it has some specific/concrete type (which is determined by the caller); `dyn …` is a specific type (a trait object) underlying which is some other specific/concrete type that implements the trait, but nobody cares what that underlying type is.

Comment: @eggyal thanks a lot for your explanation, forgive my poor English, I understand your mean but cannot express it correctly. By the way, is there any way to use generic type in function body? like ```return F(...)```

Comment: Yes, absolutely: if the generic type parameter implements a trait, you can call trait methods and access its associated types e.g. `F::poll(…)` and `F::Output`—but that’s no good to you here because `Future` does not define any constructors.  Perhaps you’re seeking to replace `dyn Trait` with `impl Trait`, which (when in return position) has a concrete type determined by the function definition rather than the caller.

Comment: @eggyal got it, but I need some time to rebuild my mind set, you know , i am from golang, contrast to rust, every thing in golang is simple and directly. But I love rust, beause of it's generic type system and macro.